# How Can I Remove A Merged Feature Branch Using Rebase?

Tags: git

I have merged lots of feature branches to develop using `git merge --no-ff` creating merge commits via pull requests and now I have started testing the release.

During testing the business have decided to remove one of the features.

For instance, in this diagram (not mine) I would be trying to remove the brown branch "Merge pull request #8661.." from history.
You can see that it isn't a simple linear case as there are overlapping commits and merges from the first commit of the branch to the merge point.

[image: git branch merge diagram]

Using `git revert` and making a new commit doesn't really work as it leaves the feature commits in the history which makes it tricky to being them back in the next release due to this caveat of `git revert`

> Reverting a merge commit declares that you will never want the tree changes brought in by the merge.
> As a result, later merges will only bring in tree changes introduced by commits that are not ancestors of the previously reverted merge.
> This may or may not be what you want.

So what I am trying to achieve is "undo" rather than "revert".

Interactive rebase would seem like it *could* be the way to go but I would need to be able to identify all the commit hashes that made up that feature branch, which isn't always easy in a big repo.
I would need to make sure the other merge commits stayed in place and the history wasn't flattened (`--preserve-merges`?)

What is a good way to go about this?

Note: I'm not worried about the fact that I'm rewriting history or that the hashes are changing as it will be well communicated to the team and I am OK with fixing conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

> Using `git revert` and making a new commit doesn't really work as it leaves the feature commits in the history which makes it tricky to being them back in the next release...

You *can* completely rewrite your history, but the caveat isn't as tricky as it seems. By far the simplest course of action in your case is to revert the merge commit with:

```
git revert <merge-commit-id> -m 1
```

and later when it's time to put the feature back in, you simply revert the revert:

```
git revert <first-revert-commit-id>
```

Alternatively, instead of reverting a revert, you can change the commit IDs of the original branch, and then they can be brought back in with a regular merge. There are multiple ways to change the commit IDs, for instance `cherry-pick` the range of commits from the original branch, or `rebase` that branch with the `--no-ff` or `--force-rebase` options against the `merge-base` commit which normally would skip the rebase with nothing to do, but in this case would just rewrite the commits on that branch to obtain new commit IDs.

**Tip:** When you revert a commit, by default, the first few lines of the commit message include the commit subject and ID you're reverting, and when it's a merge commit, it also includes the parent commit information so you know which *way* the merge was reverted. I recommend appending extra comments after that explaining why you are reverting. This helps when viewing the history of the file, to see a comment explaining why some changes are flip flopping back and forth.

All that said, if you still prefer to rewrite your branch and completely remove the merge from the history, you can try an interactive rebase with the [`--rebase-merges`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#Documentation/git-rebase.txt--r) (`-r`) option. This is the newer version of the `--preserve-merges` option you mentioned, which was recently removed. The caveat with the `-r` option is that any merge commits you attempt to rewrite that had conflicts resolved during that merge, will have to be re-resolved. Fortunately, in your case, it appears that all of your merge commits are from Pull Requests, so it's unlikely to be an issue for you. Any conflicts you have are most likely to be caused by removing the PR in question, and if that happens you'll need to resolve those conflicts regardless of whether you `rebase` or `revert`.

As for this problem:

> I would need to be able to identify all the commit hashes that made up that feature branch, which isn't always easy in a big repo.

I think you have plenty of options here for determining those commits:

1. Visually trace the graph to figure out which commit IDs you need to remove from the interactive rebase instructions.
2. Open the PR in the tool you used to complete it, and it should list all the commits that were brought in.
3. Just run this command, where `X` is the commit ID of the merge you wish to undo: `git log X^1..X^2 --oneline` and you'll get a list of the commits you need to drop from the interactive rebase.

Or, another option would be to attempt to remove the commits from the rebase completely, and skip the interactive rebase altogether:

```
# let X be the merge commit to remove
# create a copy of the release branch for sanity purposes
git branch temp-branch release-branch-name
git rebase X temp-branch --onto X^1 --rebase-merges
```

Comment: "Revert revert" is no good. I now have 3 changes of the files and that branch is still part of the history of the release branch

Comment: @opticyclic yeah, that's true, but not necessarily "bad", since that literally is what the history of your release branch is. I always recommend putting additional comments in Revert commits explaining what's going on by appending the default message with, e.g. "... This feature will be brought back in a later release." And on the revert of the revert, appending the message with "...This release of this feature was delayed until now."

Comment: @opticyclic you need to weigh the pros and cons of showing a historical record that you changed your mind about something, vs rewriting a shared branch that may have other consequences. You could try something like `git rebase -i --rebase-merges` and it may work well for you. This works best when you don't have any existing merge commits that previously resolved conflicts in them.

Comment: Adding comments to the reverts certainly helps, however, it makes the log graph harder to read as you can't easily visually follow the reverts back to the original commits.

Comment: @opticyclic agreed. That's why when you revert, the first few lines by default include the commit you're reverting, and when it's a merge commit, it also includes the parent commit information so you know which *way* you reverted. I like to append extra comments after that. I definitely try to avoid reverting, and also reverting a revert, when possible, but sometimes it just happens.

Comment: @opticyclic I've summarized these comments into the answer.